# Conference abstract: AutoCorrect underline not removed

Tags: conference, errors-erratum, abstract

I started my PhD last August, and recently I submitted an abstract to a major conference. After submitting it I noticed that on one of my figures, which contain multiple subfigures, I have forgotten to remove some of the red AutoCorrect squiggly underlines in the figure headings. As the abstract deadline has been reached, it is not possible for me to correct this and submit a new version. I really don't know how I could have missed this considering how carefully I worked on the abstract, but somehow this just slipped by both me and my supervisor who reviewed the abstract. I feel that the research itself is of high enough quality to warrant a presentation, but now I'm worried that this stupid mistake may affect my overall score under the review process.

My question is therefore: how serious is such a "cosmetic" error when the abstract is reviewed? If anyone familiar with the review process can inform me how much emphasis is put on this, then I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: In CS/HCI conferences I sometimes get paper that follow old or even completely wrong templates (like a single column format), display the author names in full (when they were supposed to be anonymised). A squiggly line should not be cause for serious concern.

If it works like our field, you'll have the chance to submit a camera ready if it is accepted. Perhaps, consider using LaTeX next time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I'm glad to hear that this should not be a course for serious concern even though the subfigures are plagued with some squiqqly lines. I will definitely consider using LaTex next time!

Comment: @TheWanderer Please convert your comment to an answer.